# A probabilistic inequality

Tags: probability, reference-request

If $A_1,\dotsc,A_k$ are positive-probability events in a probability space, then
  $$ k^2 \le P(A_1\cup...\cup A_k) \cdot \Bigg( \sum_{I=1}^k \frac{1}{P(A_i)}  +   
 2\sum_{1\le i<j\le k} \frac{P(A_i\cap A_j)}{P(A_i) P(A_j)} \Bigg). $$

Does this inequality have a "standard" name? BTW, is there any standard name / notation for the quotient $P(A_i\cap A_j)/(P(A_i) P(A_j)$, or maybe for its inverse?

Thanks!